# Distributed Process in monad transformer

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, state-monad, cloud-haskell

Im toying with implementing a gossip based cluster membership backend for the so called `cloud-haskell` or is it `Distributed.Process`.. anyway Im trying to get away with handeling state without `ioref`  or `MVars` and instead using a state transformer and putting the `Process` monad on the bottom, like so:

```
type ClusterT = StateT ClusterState
type Cluster a = ClusterT Process a
```

This works fairly well using `Control.Distributed.Process.Lifted` (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributed-process-lifted) allowing you to do something like this:

```
mystatefulcomp :: Cluster ()
mystatefulcomp = do
   msg <- expect :: Cluster String
   old_state <- get
   say $ "My old state was " ++ (show old_state)
   put $ modifyState curr_state msg
   mystatefulcomp

main = do
   Right transport <- createTransport '127.0.0.1' '3000' (\n -> ('127.0.0.1', n) defaultTCPParameters
   node <- newLocalNode transport initRemoteTable
   runProcess node (evalStateT mystatefulcomp initialstate)
   where initialstate = ClusterState.empty
```

this works resonably well and allows me to structure my program fairly well, i can keep my state functional and thread it along in the `Cluster` monad.

This all break tho when i try to use `receiveWait` and `match` to receive messages.

lets rewrite `statefulcomp` to do something else using `receiveWait`

```
doSomethingWithString :: String -> Cluster ()
doSomethingWithString str = do
   s < get
   put $ modifyState s str    

mystatefulcomp :: Cluster ()
mystatefulcomp = do
   old_state <- get
   receiveWait [ match doSomthingWithString ]
   new_state <- get
   say $ "old state " ++ (show old_state) ++ " new " ++ (show new_state)
```

This wont work since the `match` function is of type `(a -> Process b) -> Match b` but we want it to be of type `(a -> Cluster b) -> Match b`. And here is where i get out on thin ice. As i understand `Control.Distributed.Process.Lifted` rexposes `Control.Distributed.Process` functions lifted into the tansformer stack allowing you to use functions like `expect` and `say` but does not rexposes `match`, `matchIf` and so on..

Im really struggeling with this trying to find a work around or a way of re implementing `match` and its friends to the form of `MonadProcess m => (a -> m b) -> Match b`.

Any insights is apriciated.

**edit**

So after som fiddeling about I came up with the following

```
doSomethingWithString :: String -> Cluster ()
doSomethingWithString str = do
   s < get
   put $ modifyState s str

doSomethingWithInt :: Int -> Cluster ()
...

mystatefulcomp :: Cluster ()
mystatefulcomp = do
   old_state <- get
   id =<< receiveWait [ match $ return . doSomethingWithString
                      , match $ return . doSomethingWithInt ]
   new_state <- get
   say $ "old state " ++ (show old_state) ++ " new " ++ (show new_state)
```

This works fairly well but I am still curious about how good of a design this is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Michael Snoyman points [out](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/06/readert-design-pattern) [in a](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/06/understanding-resourcet) [series](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/06/tale-of-two-brackets) of [blog](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/07/announcing-new-unliftio-library) [posts](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/07/the-rio-monad) (that's 5 links), wrapping `StateT` around `IO` is a bad idea. You just stumbled over one instance where that surfaces.

```
mystatefulcomp :: Cluster ()
mystatefulcomp = do
   old_state <- get
   receiveWait [ match doSomethingWithString ]
   new_state <- get
```

The problem is what ends up in `new_state` if `doSomethingWithString` throws an error. The `old_state`? Some intermediate state from `doSomethingWithString` before the exception? You see, the very fact that we are wondering makes this approach no less bad than just storing the state in an `IORef` or `MVar`.

Apart from questionable semantics, this can't even be implemented without `distributed-process` being rewritten to use [`MonadBaseControl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-1.0.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#t:MonadBaseControl) everywhere. This is exactly why `distributed-process-lifted` fails to deliver, because it just wraps around the primitives from `distributed-process`.

So, what I would do here instead is to pass around a `data Config = Config { clusterState :: MVar ClusterState }` environment (Oh look, [`Process`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributed-process-0.7.3/docs/src/Control-Distributed-Process-Internal-Types.html#Process) does that, too!). Possibly with `ReaderT` which interacts with `IO` in a sane way, plus you can easily lift any number of nested occurences of `Process` to `ReaderT Config Process` yourself.

Repeating the message of Michael's blog posts: `StateT` isn't bad in general (in a pure transformer stack, that is), just for cases where we wrap `IO` in some way. I encourage you to read those posts, they were very inspiring for me, so here they are again:

1. https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/06/readert-design-pattern
2. https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/06/understanding-resourcet
3. https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/06/tale-of-two-brackets
4. https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/07/announcing-new-unliftio-library
5. https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/07/the-rio-monad